# I installed opencv3 with conda, yet I can only import cv2... is this correct?

Tags: python-3.x, conda, opencv3.1

I am anaconda on a mac os x Yosemite, running python 3.5. I used the following command from anaconda's [website](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3)

`conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0`

The terminal read out nothing to do with opencv2.
[image: Terminal read out]

However, in the ipython console I am unable to import cv3. I get,

`conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0`

Yet.... interestingly enough I able import cv2. I have read a bit that opencv can be a tricky and wily beast to get working...

Also anaconda specifically says that I have only the opencv3 package.

So, I am wondering... even though I am using opencv3 maybe for some reason it still uses cv2 as the package name to import?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: [There's no `cv3`](http://answers.opencv.org/question/63405/why-do-python-bindings-for-v3-still-use-package-name-cv2/)

Comment: @Miki Huh, so even though its 3.1 the way to call it is with cv2?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is just that simple... import cv2 even if you have opencv3.x.

Thank you Miki.